# Issue with setting start and end date in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script

```
function testEvent(){
   var date = new Date();
   var start = todayStart(date);
   var end = tomorrowEnd(date);
}

function todayStart(date123){
  var dateHolder = date123;
  dateHolder.setHours(15, 0, 0, 0);
  return dateHolder;
}

function tomorrowEnd(tomorrow){
  var dateHolder1 = tomorrow;
  dateHolder1.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  dateHolder1.setHours(14, 59, 59, 59);
  return dateHolder1;
}
```

I am having issues with the above code. end and start are both returning 14:59:59:59 unless I comment out end, which then results in start being 15:00:00:00. End follows start so I am not sure what the problem is here. Why would end being commented out fix the problem(in a way) but it existing cause problems. Sorry if this has been asked before but specific help is always easiest. Also, this is on google apps script.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the same Date object into both todayStart and tomorrowEnd and they both manipulate that object. Since tomorrowEnd is the last thing called, that is the result you're seeing.

Comment: Do you happen to have a recommendation? Should I copy the date object into a placeHolder variable?

Answer (score 0):

Objects are pass by reference in Javascript. You need two separate objects here.
Try this:

```
function testEvent(){
   var startdate = new Date();
  var enddate = new Date();
   var start = todayStart(startdate);
   var end = tomorrowEnd(enddate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

below is a working version of your code, as mentioned in the other answers you need to create separate date objects;

```
function testEvent(){
   var date = new Date();
   var start = todayStart(date);
   var end = tomorrowEnd(date);
  Logger.log('start = '+start+'  end = '+end);
}

function todayStart(date123){
  var dateHolder = new Date(date123);
  dateHolder.setHours(15, 0, 0, 0);
  return dateHolder;
}

function tomorrowEnd(tomorrow){
  var dateHolder1 = new Date(tomorrow);
  dateHolder1.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  dateHolder1.setHours(14, 59, 59, 59);
  return dateHolder1;
}
```

result :

[image]